# What are the exact steps of setting up jfrog artifactory pro on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, artifactory

I am looking for the exact steps for setting up jfrog artifactory pro on AWS and then accessing it from the browser(Browser access must be only from inside the corporation network). I am following the steps from
https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/artifactory-install-and-configurations-guide/
https://github.com/ravdy/DevOps/blob/master/Artifactory/Setup_Artifactory.md

Do I need to setup a reverse proxy? If so the steps of doing that too would be helpful.

I am very new to AWS and jfrog artifactory and reverse proxy stuff( 1 week experience in all these). So I am not able to find the correct resource to get it done.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use the official installation steps as provided here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory

If you want to use air gapped environment, suggest downloading once into the network a Linux Archive installation and go ahead with install. If Docker is a possibility, download the images locally and install using docker compose.